# Slow write/save speed for files on network

Tags: save, file

I noticed my VIM write/save file for a network path is quite slow.

I found out VIM saves files with approximated speed of 20mbps (2.5MB/s).
Network is 1Gb/s local area network so I believe the bandwidth is not a problem.
Notepad text editor or Notepad++ saves the same file 10 times faster.
It does not make difference if I have access via windows share and UNC path (`\\server_name`) or map it as local drive.

I made all tests with a clean VIM (`gvim.exe -u NONE`) so I believe this not a plugin issue.

What else can I check to speed up file saving?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Does the situation improve if you disable swap files with `:set noswapfile`? If so, you might consider either disabling them unconditionally or setting the `'directory'` option to ensure swap files are on local drives and not on a network share...

Comment: Using no swap change nothing, the speed is still low at saving file.

Comment: How are you editing over the network? Over a graphical ssh connection or using the builtin netrw?

Comment: The file is open with gvim by Windows 10 file manager via UNC path or mapped network drive.

Comment: This issue seems to be more about Windows shares than about Vim itself (even though Vim seems to be the only program running into this issue...) I wonder if you would have more luck asking about it (from the Windows share point of view) on [Superuser Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com)?

Comment: Ah I see you found a solution! Please post that as an answer rather than an update to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem compiling VIM with bigger write buffer size (\src\structs.h).

Default value

```
#define WRITEBUFSIZE    8192    // size of normal write buffer
```

My new value

```
#define WRITEBUFSIZE    8192*1024   // size of normal write buffer
```

VIM write speed to network drive is similar to Notepad++ now, it's around 300 Mbps in my case.